# React multiple input field onChange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm trying to add an extra input field if user clicks add input button and store those values as an object:

```js
const {useState } = React;

const InviteUser = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([
    {
      email: "",
      role: ""
    }
  ]);

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setUserDetails([
      {
        email: "",
        role: ""
      }
    ]);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    let newUserDetails = [...userDetails];
    newUserDetails[index] = { ...userDetails[index], [name]: value };
    setUserDetails({ newUserDetails });
  };

  const addInput = () => {
    setUserDetails([...userDetails, { email: "", role: "" }]);
  };

  return (
    userDetails.length >= 0 && (
      <div>
        {[...userDetails].map((el, index) => (
          <form key={index + el} name={el}>
            <div>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                value={el.email}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Enter Email Address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="roles"
                required
                value={el.role}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Role"
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        ))}
        <div>
          <button label="Invite Another?" onClick={addInput}>
            Add input
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Invite</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleCancel()}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
};




 ReactDOM.render(
       <InviteUser/>,
       document.getElementById("react")
     );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

A state is an array of objects that holds email and role:

```
const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([
    {
      email: "",
      role: ""
    }
  ]);
```

handleChange function which updates the state by pushing an object (of users inputs values from each individual row) into an array:

```
  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    let newUserDetails = [...userDetails];
    newUserDetails[index] = { ...userDetails[index], [name]: value };
    setUserDetails({ newUserDetails });
  };
```

and addInput function adds new input fields row:

```
  const addInput = () => {
    setUserDetails([...userDetails, { email: "", role: "" }]);
  };
```

And return JSX:

```
return (
    userDetails.length >= 0 && (
      <InputsContainer>
        {[...userDetails].map((el, index) => (
          <form key={index + el} name={el} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <EmailContainer>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                value={el.email}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Enter Email Address"
              />
            </EmailContainer>
            <RolesContainer>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="roles"
                required
                value={el.role}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Role"
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
              />
            </RolesContainer>
          </form>
        ))}
        <InviteButtonContainer>
          <button label="Invite Another?" onClick={addInput}>
            Add input
          </button>
        </InviteButtonContainer>
        <SubmitButtonsContainer>
          <button onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>Invite</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleCancel()}>Cancel</button>
        </SubmitButtonsContainer>
      </InputsContainer>
    )
  );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems:

1. In `setUserDetails` you return the array wrapped in an object, instead of just returning the array.
2. In the roles field you take the value from `el.role` insted of `el.roles`.

In addition, since you update the current state, based on a previous one, it's better to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```js
const {useState } = React;

const createNewEntry = () => ({ email: "", role: "" });

const InviteUser = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(() => [createNewEntry()]);

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setUserDetails([createNewEntry()]);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setUserDetails(userDetails => {
      const newUserDetails = [...userDetails];
      newUserDetails[index] = { ...userDetails[index], [name]: value };
      return newUserDetails;
    });
  };

  const addInput = () => {
    setUserDetails([...userDetails, createNewEntry()]);
  };

  return (
    userDetails.length >= 0 && (
      <div>
        {[...userDetails].map((el, index) => (
          <form key={index + el} name={el}>
            <div>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
                value={el.email}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Enter Email Address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="roles"
                required
                value={el.roles}
                style={{ marginTop: 17 }}
                placeholder="Role"
                onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        ))}
        <div>
          <button label="Invite Another?" onClick={addInput}>
            Add input
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Invite</button>
          <button onClick={() => handleCancel()}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <InviteUser/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```